# Intent-Filter for Whatsapp -> share image

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter, whatsapp

If you try to share an Image with Whatsapp, it will give you a list where you can choose:
like Camera,Gallery etc. now i would like to place my app in this list. I Saw some apps like "paint for whatsapp" where this was possible. I tried "android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE"
but this only replaces the System-Camera. I want to have a new point in the List.
Thanks in advance
Jonas

Comment: We are going to need a lot more information before we can help you. Do you know what kind of intent filter you need to be in that list?

Comment: i think it should be one like calling a gallery or getting a picture... thats the question more or less :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" /> 
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"  /> 
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own Intent-Action or appear in other lists when using different itentfilter configurations, see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html for more details.