# How to share a image from my app to whatsapp in android?

Tags: android

I receive an error when I press a `Button`.

```
InputStream y11 = getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.step_000);
Bitmap b11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(y11);

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("image/png");
intent.setPackage("com.whats app.android");
intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, b11);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share with"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this;

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("image/png");

Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://your package name/"+R.drawable.ic_launcher);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hello, This is test Sharing");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Send your image"));
```

Also look into this: [Returning an Image to whatsapp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15900842/returning-an-image-to-whatsapp)

Comment: This code is working but I am getting black portion in image in place of transparent portion. Please help me out.