# How to send image directly into the chat using mime type in whatsapp

Tags: android, android-intent, share, mime-types

I have a working application which shares images over WhatsApp. I used `mime type` to redirect selected image to WhatsApp.
But when the attachment of image is selected from the chat/WhatsAppand after selecting my application it start again with the list of various contacts in WhatsApp.

What I want is to share image directly in the chat box using my application.
Here please understand by this:

[image: when attachment selected.]

When attachment is selected

[image: directed to apps main page]

directed to apps main page

[image: random image selected and shared to whatsapp]

Random image selected and shared to whatsapp

[image: but it sends to contacts and groups instead the chat box]

But it sends to contacts and groups instead the chat box :(

Here goes my sharing code:

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.full_image_view);
        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

        File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        String fileName = "desi.png";
        File dest = new File(sd, fileName);
        try {
            FileOutputStream out;
            out = new FileOutputStream(dest);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.item:
                Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(dest);
                Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
                shareIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
                shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
                shareIntent.setType("image/*");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent,   getResources().getText(R.string.share)));
                return true;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to return a result. Do it the following way (taken from [android developer training](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/filters.html) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16763688/2829009=)):

Change your code in the switch-statement:

```
case R.id.item:
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(dest);
    if (shouldReturnResult()) {
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND, uri); //or ACTION_PICK
        this.setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, shareIntent); //set result
        this.finish(); //exit activity
    } else {
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
        shareIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
        shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
        shareIntent.setType("image/*");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.share)));
    }
    return true;
```

and add this code-snippet:

```
private boolean shouldReturnResult() {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (intent!=null && intent.getType()!=null) {
        return intent.getType().indexOf("image/") != -1;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This way your app returns an image if you open it via whatsapp, but you can still share images if an user started the "normal way".

**Note:**
It would be better for the users if you return the result to whatsapp as soon as they select an image, so that they don't have to click the share-icon again.

Comment: Somewhere in your activity, for example after the `onOptionsItemSelected` method.

Comment: it says This method must return a result of type boolean
then... `shouldReturnResult` is never used locally...

Comment: Ups. Had 2 errors in the code. I changed the code of the code-snippet (the _else_ was missing) and the switch-statement (missing `()` near `shouldReturnResult`).

Comment: okay but it still showing a Warning: `The method shouldReturnResult() from the type FullImageActivity is never used locally`.

Comment: Please undo your changes and recopy the code. `shouldReturnResult()` should be from the type boolean and used in `if(shouldReturnResult())`.

Comment: not working 
still having the same problem, the app again ask to share via! option when initialized from whatsapp.

Comment: Try to change ACTION_SEND to ACTION_PICK.

Comment: still not working...
should i use `setPakage` for specific whatsapp?

Comment: not working even after i implement the `setPakage` to whatsapp.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
    shareIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
    shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);// uri of perticular picture ( from gallary or camera pic
    shareIntent.setType("image/*");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent,getResources().getText(R.string.share)));
```