# Set Wallpaper in whatsapp after getting the path

Tags: android, android-wallpaper

I am following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16763688/2715065) to accomplish my task. Everything works well except the last part,

```
if(result!=null)
{

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image saved in Gallery !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    if(isinint) //check if any app cares for the result
    {
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND, Uri.fromFile(new File(result.toString()))); //Create a new intent. First parameter means that you want to send the file. The second parameter is the URI pointing to a file on the sd card. (openprev has the datatype File)

        ((Activity) ImageListActivity.this).setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, shareIntent); //set the file/intent as result
        ((Activity) ImageListActivity.this).finish(); //close your application and get back to the requesting application like GMail and WhatsApp
        return; //do not execute code below, not important
    }
}
```

At last nothing crash but wallpaper is also not set in whatsapp.

Can anyone please let me know why it is not working?

Any help is appriciated.

Thanks

Comment: Where do you set isinint? Did you debug the code and checked at what point it stops working? Please edit your question and give more informations.

Comment: @JamesCameron Yes, I already debug it, it executes all the lines, no error & then I go to whatsapp chat where wallpaper doesnt set

Comment: Found an answer yet? I imagine that the ACTION_SEND Intent may be wrong as it may be called with another intention. Please debug the Intent you get when the app is called.

Comment: @JamesCameron No, If you solved it pls answer here, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code..

```
OnButtonClick(){
ImageProcessing imageProcessing = new ImageProcessing();
            Bitmap bitmap = imageProcessing.takeScreenshot(getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(R.id.view_thought));
            imageProcessing.saveBitmap(bitmap);
            Intent intent = imageProcessing.setAsOption(this,imageProcessing.getSavedImagePath());
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Set image as"), 200);
}
```

And Implement a new class ImageProcessing

```
public class ImageProcessing {
private File imagesPath;
public void saveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    imagesPath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/screenshot.jpg");
    FileOutputStream fos;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(imagesPath);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("POS", e.getMessage(), e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("POS", e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
public File getSavedImagePath(){
    imagesPath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/screenshot.jpg");
    return imagesPath;
}

public Bitmap takeScreenshot(View rootView) {
    rootView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    return rootView.getDrawingCache();
}
public Intent setAsOption(Context cntxt,File imagesPath){
    /*File imagesPath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/screenshot.jpg");*/
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_ATTACH_DATA);
    if(imagesPath.exists()){
        Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(cntxt, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID+".Utility.GenericFileProvider",imagesPath);

        intent.setDataAndType(contentUri, "image/jpg");
        intent.putExtra("mimeType", "image/jpg");
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(cntxt,"Not a wallpaper",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return intent;
}
```

}

And in menifest add :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />
```